# Как быстро взять у числа пять первых цифр?

Tags: javascript

Есть число:
53.90777587521798

Как у него взять первые пять цифр, так что бы при этом это осталось числом а не строкой
Я знаю что можно сначала превратить это число в строку и потом методом substring взять. Но может быть можно как то проще?

Comment: Вообще первых или после запятой?

Comment: Первые пять цифр без запятой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так:

```js
console.log(Math.round(53.90777587521798*1e5)/1e5);
console.log(parseInt(53.90777587521798*1e5)/1e5); // или так.
// если пять цифр, считая цифры и до запятой, то так:
console.log(Math.round(53.90777587521798*1e3)/1e3);
console.log(parseInt(53.90777587521798*1e3)/1e3);
```

Comment: А что значат вот эти вот 1e5

Comment: [Экспоненциальная запись](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C). Эквивалент 1 * 10^5 (в JS - `1 * 10 ** 5`, будет тот же результат, что и от `1e5`).